# Firestore Import - Export gCloud NOT_FOUND: Project 'projectID' does not exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

What I want is to clone a project that I have in Firebase and create another project that is the same but with another Google account. I have full access to both accounts. Is this possible?

Then I am following the following documentation to export and then import data into Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import

So -in the gloud console- I tried the following in the original project (Storage):

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://punkutravel.appspot.com
```

and I get:

```
outputUriPrefix: gs://punkutravel.appspot.com/2019-10-27T17:09:39_35393
```

All good.

So then I want to import that data into another project (with another account)

and I execute the following:

```
gcloud beta firestore import gs://punkutravel.appspot.com/2019-10-27T17:09:39_35393
```

and I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.firestore.import) NOT_FOUND: Project
>   'anqasky-5861e' does not exist.

I have even assigned the permission to the source account and vice versa, but it still hasn't worked out.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and finally I've figured out the solution.

SOLUTION: You need to go to your Firebase console [console.firebase.google.com](https://console.firebase.google.com/)

And you have to pick Datastore type before you can import something.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how can we pick the Datastore type ?

Comment: I believe in the past it used to be a choice between creating a "Cloud Firestore" or "Realtime Database". All you need to do is go to the Cloud Firestore area in the console and click the button at the top that says Create

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create a Firestore database on the console. You are getting that error because the database itself does not exist, so you can't import data into it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is a typo in the name of the project?

You can see your available projects with: `gcloud projects list`.

You can change your default project to one from that list with `gcloud config set core/project PROJECT_NAME`, or pass `--project=PROJECT_NAME` to your command.