# Firebase project doesn't exist when trying to move data moving data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having an issue with moving data from one firebase project to another, the process is smooth until the point when I have to import data from a bucket into my destination project I get an error saying that the project i'm importing data into doesn't exist, despite the fact that i'm located inside the project:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore Import - Export gCloud NOT\_FOUND: Project 'projectID' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582902/firestore-import-export-gcloud-not-found-project-projectid-does-not-exist)